# Django - sorting object based on user defined order in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want the user to be able to order a list of objects in a table using javascript. Then, in a django function I would like to sort those object based on the same ordering, not on an attribute.

Is it possible? I was thinking about passing a list of pk from the template to the view and then ordering the objects according to this list, but I have not found a way to do it yet.

[image]

Comment: Consider using django-tables2 (http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create your tables. It gives you a lot of control over ordering, as well as letting users r order by any column.

Comment: good idea, I already use it for listing, but here the order is important not only for viewing data but in processing, also the ordering would not be based on attribute but on user preference only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with queryset. Try following:

```
pk_list = [2, 1, 3, 4]
pk2obj = {obj.pk: obj for obj in Model.objects.all()}
objects_ordered = [pk2obj[pk] for pk in pk_list]
```

`pkg2obj` is mapping between pk and model instance object. To make a dictionary I used [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

If you want to omit deleted objects:

```
objects_ordered = [pk2obj[pk] for pk in pk_list if pk in pk2obj]
```

Else if you want to replace deleted objects with default value (`None` in following code):

```
objects_ordered = [pk2obj.get(pk, None) for pk in pk_list]
```

Comment: could you explain a little about how it works, I have never seen such syntax before especially: objects_ordered = [pk2obj[pk] for pk in pk_list]

Comment: Do you think your solution would work if an object.pk that is in pk_list doesnt exist (if the object was deleted elsewhere for instance) because I would like to save the pk_list in a model field

Comment: @Burton449, Current code raise `KeyError` in such case. If object was deleted it should be omitted? or replaced by default value like `None`?

Comment: Do you know if its possible to do something like that if pk_list is not an array but a comma-separated integer string like django `models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField`?

Comment: Fetch that row and convert it to a list of integers.  `[int(x) for x in obj.comma_sep_int_field.split(',')]`. Then, apply the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to solve this exact problem before.

If you want the user to be able to reorder them into a user-defined order, you can easily define a field to store this order.

As you say, initially, you could serve them in order according to `id` or an `upload_date` [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield). But you could also have an [PositiveIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) in the model, named `position` or `order`, to represent the user-defined order.

```
class MediaItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Whenever a user changes the order on the frontend, the JS can send the new order as an array of objects (ie. `new_order = [{"pk":3, "position":1}, {"pk":1, "position":2}, {"pk":2, "position":3}]`). The view can look up each instance by `pk`, and change the `position`:

```
for obj in new_order:
    media_item = MediaItem.objects.get(pk=obj['pk'])
    media_item.position = obj['position']
    media_item.save()
```

Then always query using

```
objects_ordered.objects.order_by('position')
```

That's how we managed to do it. If you have more specific questions regarding this approach, feel free to ask in the comments.

**Edit:**

If the same object can be a member of many different groups or lists, and you want to store the position of the *membership* within that list, you can achieve this using a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). A through model is useful when you need to store data that relates to the relationship between two objects that are related. In addition to the `MediaItem` class shown above, this is what your other models would look like:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    media_items = models.ManyToManyField(MediaItem,
                                         related_name = 'album_media_items',
                                         through = 'Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album,
                              related_name = 'album')
    media_item = models.ForeignKey(MediaItem,
                                   related_name = 'media_item')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then, you could query the `Membership` instances, instead of the `MediaItem` instances.

```
# get id of list, or album...
alb = Album.objects.get(pk=id_of_album)
media_items = Membership.objects.filter(album=alb).order_by('position')
for item in media_items:
    # return the items, or do whatever...
    # keep in mind they are now in the user-defined order
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, the only thing I am not sure about it is that in my situation there would be many different positions for each items to save, because there would be many lists to order with the same items. Thats why I prefer to save the position in a List Model instead of Item model field.

Comment: @Burton449 Ah, wow. Your situation is even more similar to the one we had to solve! You can store the "membership" in a through model. I'll edit my answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: @Burton449 Sure thing, hope it was helpful

Comment: I can't figure what strategy would be the best to populate the position field, do you use hidden fields and a jquery function? Can you elaborate a little on that? Thank you

Comment: @Burton449 Since that is beyond the scope of the question, I would ask that as a separate question, in case others need to find the answer. You can use data- atribute tags.

Comment: @Burton449 (sorry, SO isn't letting me edit that comment, and I hit Enter prematurely)...here's the edit: Since that is significantly beyond the scope of the question, it would be nice to have that as a separate question, in case others need to find the answer. Use a data tag, and jquery will return them as an array inside the jquery object, in the order they appear in the HTML (ie, the order the user has chosen). `<li data-foo="pk">`. Then pass that to the backend on a POST as an array of objects. If that's confusing, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
pk_list = [1,5,3,9]

foo = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=pk_list)

#Order your QuerySet in base of your pk_list using Lambda

order_foo = sorted(foo, key = lambda:x , pk_list.index(x.pk))
```